# How to convert a string in array format '["abc","xyz"]' to a useable array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to parse a response from an api and pulling my hair out.

Here's a simplified version of the response:

```
[{"id":123456,"account":6789}]
```

So I'm basically working with a string that looks like this:

```
'[{"id":123456,"account":6789}]'
```

I just need to check that "id" exists, because that means my POST worked fine. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to take that string and get something usable.

How can I get to the value of "id"?

Comment: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) https://3v4l.org/FUW3S

Comment: @Nick, tried that, json_decode($str)[0]["id] gives me a fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: `json_decode($string, true)` lol, see how PHP is cool ?

Comment: @MattB take a look at my demo in the comment. I show you how to process that string as either an object or an array.

Comment: @Nick `json_decode($string, true)` the `true` is what I was missing and it was driving me nuts. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MattB no worries - I probably should have made it more clear in my demo that I was changing the second parameter to json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your string to an array of `JSON` objects using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
json_decode($response_str, true)
```

Comment: and use the optional flag, `json_decode($response_str, true)` to get an array instead of an object.

Comment: @TCooper this is what I was missing, so silly. Thanks!